# how to change navigationitem title color

Tags: ios, swift

I think all day to change the navigation Bar title color, but it doesn't work. this is my code:

```
var user: User? {
    didSet {
        navigationItem.title = user?.name

         observeMessages()
    }
}
```

I use didSet to show the title on the navigation title.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Add this in your code . .

```
let textAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.red]
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
```

**SWIFT 4:**

```
let textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.red]
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
```

**SWIFT 4.2+:**

```
let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.red]
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
```

**Keeping all the other attributes of the title:**
If you just want change the color you could do like this:

```
if var textAttributes = navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes {
    textAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = UIColor.red
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
}
```

Comment: you rock, man. But what's the different, when I coded this on viewDidLoad:navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red] it doesn't work

Comment: thanks @熊天宇 , I can't really say why it didn't work when you coded in `viewDidLoad` until I see your full source code . By the way , I was successful while coded in `viewDidLoad` , have a look at my code `override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        user = "holla"
        let textAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.red]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
    }`

Comment: Works on tvOS to change the UIViewController title.

Comment: If your navigation bar title uses custom font then this solution works. Using the answer "Keeping all the other attributes of the title" was what I needed.

Answer (score 45):

The title color of Navigation Bar can be changed in Storyboard.

Go to *Attributes inspector* of *Navigation Controller* > *Navigation Bar* and set the desired color in *Title Color* menu.

---

[image]

Answer (score 45):

#### Solution for iOS 13

To customize the appearance of a navigation bar you need to use [`UINavigationBarAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance):

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]

navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

Comment: Thanks,
Working!

Comment: anyone who came here because of iOS15, this is the correct answer :) I've added `largeTitleTextAttributes` and the title has changed.

Answer (score 28):

**Swift 4**

set this first

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
```

then one of those should work

```
navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```

or

```
navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```

**Swift 5**

```
navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```

or

```
navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```

Answer (score 10):

For iOS 13 you have to change the color in the appearance property and for older iOS versions you can do it directly in the navigation bar property.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
} else {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Objective C:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
        [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, 
           [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:16.0], NSFontAttributeName,nil]];
```

Answer (score 4):

The didSet is called if your set the user, maybe you're setting the user's name variable and expecting the program to enter didSet. 
try setting the user.

And if you want to change the color of the text when the navigation title is changed to the name of the user just call this code.

`navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red]`

```
var user: User? {
    didSet {
        navigationItem.title = user?.name
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let newUser = User()
    newUser.name = "John Doe"
    user = newUser
}
```

Comment: So, should I set the username color??

Comment: J.Koush thank you so much,  I know this command:navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red]     But it still doesn't change...

Answer (score 4):

If you set your navigation bar's title to prefer large titles, like so:

```
navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

then you need to use the largeTitleTextAttributes property and not the titleTextAttributes property. If you set your nav title to be a large title, the titleTextAttribute is not the correct property to use. Use the largeTitleTextAttributes property, like so:

```
navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5/Xcode 11**

Write this code as extension from UINavigationBar

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    func customNavigationBar() {
        // color for button images, indicators and etc. 
        self.tintColor = UIColor.Custom.mainAppColor

        // color for background of navigation bar
        // but if you use larget titles, then in viewDidLoad must write
        // navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = // your color
        self.barTintColor = .white
        self.isTranslucent = false

        // for larget titles 
        self.prefersLargeTitles = true

        // color for large title label
        self.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.someColor]

        // color for standard title label 
        self.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.someColor]

        // remove bottom line/shadow
        self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

then in `AppDelegate.swift` call `UINavigationBar.appearance().customNavigationBar()` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function

Answer (score 4):

you can just add this line of code in your AppDelegate in the func

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

Code you will add to change title color:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(red: 0.7415059209, green: 0.5448099971, blue: 0.5051562786, alpha: 1)]
```

you can add this line as well if you wanna change the backButton color

```
  UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7415059209, green: 0.5448099971, blue: 0.5051562786, alpha: 1)
```

Finally you can add this line to change the background color:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2000651062, green: 0.1960035861, blue: 0.2000851929, alpha: 1)
```

**Note:** You can change the values dependent on the color you want
and have a happy coding day

Comment: i have code to set using UINavigationBarAppearance() but adding the below code along with appearance object worked
`UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white`

Comment: Happy that's working with you @kingkongCoder

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 4

#### create project and test this with ViewController easy to use

```
import UIKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureNavigationBar()
   }
   
   func configureNavigationBar() {
       // change title
       navigationItem.title = "Profile"
       navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

       // change title color
       let textChangeColor = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
       navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textChangeColor
       navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = textChangeColor

       // configure right bar button
       navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
       navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow_right").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss))
       navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
   }
}
```