# navigationBar title goes to default black instead of the color I set in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have been looking for a solution for a while for this bug, but haven't been able to solve it. I am setting the navigationBar title color in my main view controller in its viewWillAppear using my setUpBlueNavBar method. The problem is that after I segue to a different view controller and back to my main view controller, only the largeTitleTextAttributes property is set to white, and not the regular titleTextAttributes. Both of those properties are being set in the exact same way, so I'm not sure why the large title color is set when I go back to the main view controller, but the regular title goes back to the default black.

The method I call in my main view controller's viewWillAppear is:

```
static func setUpBlueNavBarFor(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    let whiteAttribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    if let navBar = viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar {
        navBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "0096FF")!
        navBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = whiteAttribute
        navBar.titleTextAttributes = whiteAttribute
    }
}
```

Here's a link to a gif I made to show the bug. I can't embed the gif here since this is my first post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkNoH.jpg

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706103/how-to-change-navigationitem-title-color/43706508

Comment: @Linh Ta Correct me if I’m wrong, but I believe I am setting that property the same way that is described in the top answer of the link you posted. This does set the property initially. The bug is that  after I segue to a different view controller and back to my main view controller, only the largeTitleTextAttributes property is set to white, and not the regular titleTextAttributes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put it in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: Setting up the `navigationBar` attributes in `viewDidLoad` didn't work either. I believe that by the time `viewDidLoad` gets called, view controllers aren't embedded in navigation controllers yet, so we can't set the `navigationBar` look at that point.

Comment: But you add it in you ViewController or in your NavigationViewController?

Comment: In my view contoller’s `viewDidLoad`, I call this `setUpBlueNavBarFor` method, and I pass in `self`.  `setUpBlueNavBarFor` accesses the `navigationController.navigationBar`. I embedded the view controller in the navigation controller in the storyboard file. I didn’t create a separate file for th navigation controller, if that’s what you’re asking.

Comment: I think that if you create a separate file for the **navigation controller** you will solve your problem.